# django can't show a template - how to fix

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I just made the app *users* to validate user that is already registered in database. Included url inside project directory(urls.py), executed the login page in urls.py from app directory, made the template and a link refer in base.html. It all works, however when click **Login** link return this error:
**TemplateDoesNotExist at users/login/**

I tried to rename the path according tree navigation but always return this same error. Any idea what is happening?

*Sorry my english*

**tree navigation in my project like this:**
[my_project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBP3b.png)

**urls.py(project):**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
app_name = ['app_web_gym', 'users']

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('users.urls', namespace='users')),
    path('', include('app_web_gym.urls', namespace='app_web_gym')),
]
```

**urls.py(app)**

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns= [
     path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
]
```

**base.html:**

```
<p>
    <a href="{% url 'app_web_gym:index' %}">Web Gym</a>-
    <a href="{% url 'app_web_gym:clientes' %}">Clientes</a>-
    <a href="{% url 'app_web_gym:treinos' %}">Treinos</a>-
    <a href="{% url 'app_web_gym:instrutores' %}">Instrutores</a>-
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <p>Hello, {{user.username}}.<p/>
    {% else %}
        <a href="{% url 'users:login' %}">Login</a>
    {% endif %}

</p>

{% block content %} {% endblock content %}
```

**login.html:**

```
{% extends 'app_web_gym/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% if form.errors %}
        <p>Wrong username/password. Try again.</p>
    {% endif %}

    <form method='POST' action="{% url 'users:login' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {{form.as_p}}
        <button name='submit'>Log in</button>
        <input type='hidden' name='next' value="{% url 'app_web_gym:index' %}" />
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

I printed the full error:
[TemplateDoesNotExist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEO38.png)

I noticed that says *Django tried loading these templates, in this order*, in last line ->

*/home/at_admin/prj01/app_web_gym/templates/users/login.html (Source does not exist)*

thats the wrong path to login.html the correct is

*/home/at_admin/prj01/users/templates/users/login.html* as shown in tree navigation. 
I don't know why is this happening and don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Try adding the template directory in setting.py file inside template dictionary inside ```DIR:[]```

Answer (score 0):

have you registered your app in main settings.py? It occurs sometimes when you forget to register your app

In main settings.py file:
at the end of, add one more line
INSTALLED_APPS = 
['appname'] (replace appname with the name of your app having login page)

Comment: Yes. First thing i did after created the app.

Answer (score 0):

Hey people i just deleted all the app *users* and recreated it with the same coding that i previously copied. It worked this time though still don't know what happened.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

First you should've checked if the app was installed in your settings. And as it looks in the error the files were being looked at the wrong place(app_web_gym/users/login.html) instead of (users/login.html). So I suppose you made a mistake in installing your app in settings.py.